# Multiple JSON-LD nodes for the same page

Tags: json, next.js13, schema.org, json-ld

I'm trying to do a proper JSON-LD markup for my page. I'm working on NextJS (injecting JSON-LD via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`), so I inject raw stringified JSON into the render.

Let's say my page wants to be detected as an Organization first (in order to improve rich results), I go like this:

```json
{
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Name",
        "legalName": "Legal Name",
        "url": "https://example.com",
        ... other properties
}
```

But I'd like to include as well a `"@type": "WebPage"` and a `"@type": "WebSite"` nodes to describe the page itself.

How should I proceed? Do I have to separate the main nodes or just include WebSite and WebPage as subtypes?

I've seen people do the `@graph` approach to separate nodes, but I wonder if it's the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@graph is a good approach for entities that are not referenced by anything or are referenced from several places. You can list them all in one @graph instead of creating new scripts for each.

Some entities make more sense to be embedded inside other ones, like the address of an Organization. Or a WebPage could be part of (isPartOf) a WebSite.